# three way handshake in application protocols?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

I was reading an article (https://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml) which says:

***FTP, Telnet, HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP, POP3, IMAP, SSH and any other protocol that rides over TCP also has a three way handshake performed as connection is opened.***

But isn't that only TCP(in Transport Layer) has three way handshake? how does application layer protocols like HTTP also has three way handshake, which means a six way handshake in total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article is misleading. Those protocols do not repeat the same kind of handshake on their own.

Most likely, the article just means that if you make e.g. an SMTP connection at application layer, then you necessarily also make a TCP connection at transport layer.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia
[TCP Connection establishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment):

> 1. SYN: The active open is performed by the client sending a SYN to the server. The client sets the segment's sequence number to a random
>    value A.
> 2. SYN-ACK: In response, the server replies with a SYN-ACK. The acknowledgment number is set to one more than the received sequence
>    number i.e. A+1, and the sequence number that the server chooses for
>    the packet is another random number, B.
> 3. ACK: Finally, the client sends an ACK back to the server. The sequence number is set to the received acknowledgement value i.e. A+1,
>    and the acknowledgement number is set to one more than the received
>    sequence number i.e. B+1.